# Line spacing in article

Tags: spacing, article

I have a very long article that has a mix of equations, text and figures. For some reason, it seems that some extra space is added between equations and text at random times. The extra space is not always there and in fact small changes to the text (or the dimensions of the document) seem to remove the space in some places only to appear in other places.

It seems to me that LaTeX is adding this space to fill the page in some cases. Does anyone know why this would be happening?

Sorry for not providing a MWE, as I am still unsure how to isolate this.

Comment: Perhaps you should set `\raggedbottom`?

Comment: Yes. That fixes it. The problem was that I had a long equation that was not broken (even though I had `\allowdisplaybreaks`). Thanks!